# variant='label-hidden' Not Working for lightning-input-field When field is a Rich-Text

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputrichtext

I am using Lightning input field within Lightning-Record-Edit-from ,but it seems Variant ="label-hidden" not working when field is a Rich-Text.

**Label is not getting hidden :**

```
<lightning-input-field field-name='Custom_Links_Notes__c' variant="label-hidden" > </lightning-input-field>
```

**Label is getting Hidden:**

```
<lightning-output-field field-name='Custom_Links_Notes__c' variant="label-hidden" > </lightning-output-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lightning-input-rich-text` instead of `lightning-input-field`

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/documentation)